# Change port RTP AUDIO / VIDEO PJSIP

Tags: android, voip, pjsip, linphone

I am currently on a VOIP project on Android, I am using PJSIP for my project, everything works quite well. But for a network requirement, I need to be able to configure the RTP ports for both audio and video, as can be done in other voip software like Linphone.
[image: Linphone Config]

Currently the PJSUA2 Android sample app sends video and audio packets through separate ports, but I need to be able to configure these ports which are normally above port 4000.

Any ideas, I already read all the documentation and I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think callback `on_call_sdp_created` will be helpful here ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__callback.htm#a0b298addb1c9864871b334619d99d231)).
Look at the example from desktop app below:

```
pjmedia_sdp_media *m;

for (j = 0; j < sdp->media_count; j++) {
    m = sdp->media[j];
    if (strcmp(m->desc.media.ptr, "audio") == 0) {
        m->desc.port = 7777; // <- any port here
    }
}
```